# Error : No provider for ValidateService

Tags: angular, service

I'm using `@angular/cli` . to validate the form I used validate service by creating a folder called services and then ran `ng g service validate`.
two files created and inside `validate.service`, I wrote some validation functions. then I `imported` it to my another file and created an instance inside the `constructor` to call it using `this` key word like below.

```
 constructor(private vd : ValidateService) { }
```

then I check with `ng serve`. so it give the following error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ValidateService!
```

**some says, this bundle are broken, it will fix soon and instead of it use dev bundle. what is this. I have no idea**

Comment: you need to set [provider] in @component.

Comment: how can I do it and why should I do that. is this the newest way

Comment: yes , wil you please place code of component file , so I can suggest you best

Comment: If you want one service instance per component instance, add it to the providers of the component. If you want a unique instance for the whole app, add it to the providers of the NgModule. This is covered by the documentation on services and dependency injection. Also, the CLI printed a warning when you generated the service, reminding you to add it to the providers somewhere (because it can't guess where).

Comment: yep, thanx @JBNizet. but before I used `angular-cli`, without doing this it worked properly. is there any possibility that it will add automatically to this provider when we generate it. thanx

Comment: Will you please accept my answer if it has solved you issue. please.

Answer (score 2):

Use Provider in app.module.ts file like

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
 providers: [ValidateService]
})
```

Comment: we didn't do it before. it this newest thing

Comment: @harnish no. It has always been like that. Services have always needed to be provided, and the CLI has never decided for you where to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it and latest way of doing:

First:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
 providers: [ValidateService]
})
```

Second:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'countries',
    providers: [ValidateService]
})
```

It depends on the requirement.

> If you want one service instance per component instance, add it to the
>   providers of the component. If you want a unique instance for the
>   whole app, add it to the providers of the NgModule. This is covered by
>   the documentation on services and dependency injection.
>
> As explained by @JB Nizet in comment section